# How to split a dataframe into several different sized dataframes at specified rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to split a single df into multiple df when a certain value-in this case[99,99]-is given. I have a device that takes in some data in a 2 column numeric df and then keeps taking new data and appending it to the end of .txt file. At the end of every set of data it adds a specific line that is the same every time. Basically I'm trying to unappend a df, back to its base parts. The indicator row [99,99], should never get repeated in the data.

I'm starting with something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [99, 99], [0, 5], [9, 8], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 3], [99, 99], [0.5, 0.4], [0, 0], [99, 99], [-100, -100], [99, 99]])
```

And I want to end with something like this.

```
df1 = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [99, 99]
df2 = [0, 5], [9, 8], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 3], [99, 99]
df3 = [0.5, 0.4], [0, 0], [99, 99]
df4 = [-10, -10], [99, 99]
```

I've tried using groupby but that has not produced anything useful. Should I be using a function that reads through the df to find the correct row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby` to "split" the initial dataframe:

```py
mask = (df[[0, 1]] == [99, 99]).all(axis=1)
for _, df in df.groupby(mask.shift().fillna(False).cumsum()):
    print(df)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
      0     1
0   1.0   2.0
1   3.0   4.0
2   5.0   6.0
3   7.0   8.0
4  99.0  99.0

       0     1
5    0.0   5.0
6    9.0   8.0
7    1.0   2.0
8    3.0   4.0
9    7.0   3.0
10  99.0  99.0

       0     1
11   0.5   0.4
12   0.0   0.0
13  99.0  99.0

        0      1
14 -100.0 -100.0
15   99.0   99.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use indexes of the `[99,99]` values to split the dataframe:

```py
mask = (df[[0, 1]] == [99, 99]).all(axis=1)
start = [0] + list(np.nonzero(mask)[0] + 1)
dfs = [df[start[i]:start[i+1]].reset_index(drop=True) for i in range(len(start)-1)]
```

`dfs` is now a list of dataframes:

```
      0     1
0   1.0   2.0
1   3.0   4.0
2   5.0   6.0
3   7.0   8.0
4  99.0  99.0

      0     1
0   0.0   5.0
1   9.0   8.0
2   1.0   2.0
3   3.0   4.0
4   7.0   3.0
5  99.0  99.0

      0     1
0   0.5   0.4
1   0.0   0.0
2  99.0  99.0

       0      1
0 -100.0 -100.0
1   99.0   99.0
```